# What value does BeautifulSoup return when it fails to parse HTML?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl a web page and try to extract urls which are up to Level 3. My codes are as follows:

```
import lxml.html
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

stopLevel = 3
rootUrls = ['http://ps.ucdavis.edu/']

foundUrls = {}
for rootUrl in rootUrls:
    foundUrls.update({rootUrl : {'Level':0, 'Parent':'N/A'}})

def getProtocolAndDomainName(url):
    protocolAndOther = url.split('://')
    # splitting url by '://' and retrun a list
    ptorocol = protocolAndOther[0]
    domainName = protocolAndOther[1].split('/')[0]
    # this will only return 'https://xxxxx.com'
    return ptorocol + '://' + domainName

foundUrls = {}
for rootUrl in rootUrls:
    foundUrls.update({rootUrl : 0})

def getProtocolAndDomainName(url):
    protocolAndOther = url.split('://')
    ptorocol = protocolAndOther[0]
    domainName = protocolAndOther[1].split('/')[0]
    return ptorocol + '://' + domainName


def crawl(urls, stopLevel = 5, level=1):
    nextUrls = []
    if (level <= stopLevel):
        for url in urls:
            # need to handle urls (e.g., https) that cannot be read
            try:
                openedUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(openedUrl, 'html.parser')
            except:
                print('cannot read for :' + url)

            for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
                href = a['href']
                if href is not None:
                    # for the case of a link is relative path
                    if '://' not in href:
                        href = getProtocolAndDomainName(url) + href
                    # check url has been already visited or not
                    if href not in foundUrls:
                        foundUrls.update({href: {'Level':level, 
                        'Parent':url}})
                        nextUrls.append(href)
        # recursive call
        crawl(nextUrls, stopLevel, level + 1)

crawl(rootUrls, stopLevel)
print(foundUrls)
```

After running the codes, it will show an error message as `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'soup' referenced before assignment`. I know that this problem happens because `BeautifulSoup` cannot parse `openedUrl`, and therefore, this local variable `soup` is not defined and this further causes this loop to fail. In order to solve this issue, my first solution is to set `soup` as `global` right under `def crawl(urls, stopLevel = 5, level=1):` by `global soup`. However, I was told that this doesn't solve the issue at all. My second solution is to use `if...continue` to keep the loop running when `BeautifulSoup` fails to parse, but the issue I am facing now is that no matter I set `if soup == ' '` or `if soup == None` it still doesn't work. I am wondering what value BeautifulSoup returns when it fails. Can anyone help? Or does anyone have other solutions? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when `BeautifulSoup` fails to parse a document still returns a `bs4` object, but prints a warning. It will raise a `TypeError` if you feed it something that is not a string or buffer.

In this case however the exception is most likely raised by `urllib` not `BeautifulSoup`, but you catch it and continue with the execution of your script without really handling the exception.
That causes a `NameError` exception in the next line, because `soup` is defined in the `try` block which failed and so `soup` is not defined.

As a quick fix you can use `continue` so your loop will move to the next item.

```
try:
    openedUrl = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(openedUrl, 'html.parser')
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    print('HTTP Error ' + str(e.code) + ' for: ' + url)
    continue
except KeyboardInterrupt: 
    print('Script terminated by user.')
    return
except Exception as e:
    print(e) 
    continue
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One follow up question: you mention multiple `except` blocks, do you mean I should set one block just for `openedUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()` and the other for `soup = BeautifulSoup(openedUrl, 'html.parser')`?

Comment: Not exactly. You could use another try-except block for `BeautifulSoup`, but I don't think that's necessary as it's very fault tolerant. However `urllib` could raise several exceptions which you may want to handle separately, or you may want to terminate your script with `KeyboardInterrupt` (ctrl-c), etc. I've updated my post to give you an example. Just make sure to import `urllib.error`

Answer (score 0):

You should call `read()` after opening a request to get the HTML result from the URL.

```
openedUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

**Update:** The site is blocking the built in user agent of urllib, to solve that you should mask it with Firefox's user agent.

```
        try:
            user_agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'}
            req = urllib.request.Request(url=url, headers=user_agent)
            openedUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(openedUrl, 'html.parser')
        except:
            print('cannot read for :' + url)
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup still fails to open one of the HTML even I add `.read()` in the code.

Comment: I added an update, let me know if that works. Thanks!

Comment: It still doesn't work. I guess maybe the best way is to avoid the situation when there is no value returned to soup. Any idea?

Comment: That's strange. Basically, BeautifulSoup only accepts strings, unicodes or bytes, if you feed it with any other data type other than those three it will throw an exception.

Comment: I guess I found the solution. The reason why `BeautifulSoup` fails to return a value to `soup` is because `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` fails to parse javascript first. I replace the module `urllib.request` with `selenium`. I will post the detailed code later. Thanks anyway!